# How to save a query result in a variable in Mongo JS and update documents with it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to calculate the average in .js file and insert the result of all documents inside a collection in Mongo DB, but code below doesn't work.

```
db.createCollection("myCol");

db.myCol.insert( { item: "card", qty: 15 } );
db.myCol.insert( { item: "card", qty: 92 } );

var mean = db.myCol.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "$card",
           average: { $avg: "$qty" }
         }
     }
   ]
); 

db.myCol.updateMany(
   { "item": { $eq: "card" } },
   {
     $set: { "mean" : mean },
   }
)
```

I run .js files in Mongo Shell with command

```
load (jsfile.js)
```

Comment: `$card` should be `$item`

Comment: thanks, I changed it, but mean still doesn't show up  in collection "myCol"...

Answer (score 0):

```
db.createCollection("myCol");

db.myCol.insert( { item: "card", qty: 15 } );
db.myCol.insert( { item: "card", qty: 92 } );

var mean = db.myCol.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "$item",
           average: { $avg: "$qty" }
         }
     }
   ]
).toArray(); 

db.myCol.updateMany(
   { "item": { $eq: "card" } },
   {
     $set: { "mean" : mean },
   }
)
```

you should try this one. It will work.

**Problem**

There are few operations which return `cursor` objects. In your case, the cursor object for `aggregation` query was storing at `mean` variable. That's the reason you were not getting your desired value instead a `cursor` object was getting updated in `myCol` collection.

**Solution**

I have updated the code with `toArray` method, which converts `cursor` to an array of objects.So this will work for sure.

let me know if its help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped and it works now. Also, now when I use insert method I need to specify which element from array I want to insert. For example: db.myCol.insert( average: mean[0].average)